# Access to servlet logs on localhost (jetty) when developing app for Google Application engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets, log4j, jetty

I am prototyping an java servlet application using Google application engine. Is there any way how I can access the log4j servlet logs in when testing on localhost? E.g. if I use the `Logger` class instance and I call `log.info("Request comes");` in `HttpServlet::doGet()` method I would like to use the **tail+grep** or other tools to analyze the logs during the development. Are those logs saved into some file? If using external tools is not possible I would like to see the logs at least into **Eclipse console** output.

When the application is deployed into Google (http://appengine.google.com/) cloud I can see my logs via web interface, but I need the access on localhost during the development.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j is easily configurable, I guess you know that you need to add `log4j.properties' into your classpath, etc? Other way, it have [good documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html), see *Configuration* block.

If you need to put log into file, just add:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.file=/path/to/logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n
```

where `/path/to/logfile.log` if log you can *tail+grep*

To put it into eclipse console (I guess it's just a console output), you have to add:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n
```

and don't forget about adding this appenders into an logger, for example into root logger:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
```